# Taking the address of an overloaded function template is possible, sometimes

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

On `gcc 4.9.0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct A
{
    typedef int type;
};

template<typename T> void foo(T*) { std::cout << "a" << std::endl; }
template<typename T> void foo(typename T::type*) { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T> void bar(T*) { std::cout << "a" << std::endl; }
template<typename T> void bar(typename identity<T>::type*) { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    //auto f = foo<A>; // ambiguous
    foo<A>(0); // prints "b", as the second overload is more specific

    auto b = bar<A>; // fine
    bar<A>(0); // prints "b", as the second overload is more specific (?)
    b(0); // prints "b"

    return 0;
}
```

Any clue on why the address **can** be taken, in the second case?

Comment: Clang rejects both cases.

Comment: g++ 4.9.0 appears to accept the second one

Comment: @T.C., g++ 4.9.2 compiles the code and produces output that matches OP's description.

Comment: [Demo with clang 3.6.0 (reject) && gcc 5.1.0 (accept)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56db4f441db80196)

Comment: @T.C. Clang is wrong here I think. At least in rejecting `bar`, it's correct in rejecting `foo`

Answer (score 3):

The deduction for `auto` is the same as template deduction. From [dcl.spec.auto]:

> When a variable declared using a placeholder type is initialized, [...], the deduced return type or variable type is
>   determined from the type of its initializer. If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier,
>   the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the placeholder is the `auto` *type-specifier*,
>   the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

So when we have either:

```
auto f = foo<A>;
auto b = bar<A>;
```

We are performing type deduction as if we called (to borrow T.C.'s choice of words):

```
template <typename M> void meow(M );
meow(foo<A> );
meow(bar<A> );
```

and using the deduced type `M` as the type of `f` and `b`, respectively.

But, according to [temp.deduct.type], emphasis mine:

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced
>   contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   — [...]
>   — A function parameter for which argument deduction cannot be done because the associated function
>   argument is a function, or **a set of overloaded functions** (13.4), and one or more of the following apply:
>       — **more than one function matches the function parameter type (resulting in an ambiguous deduction)**,
>   or
>       — no function matches the function parameter type, or
>       — the set of functions supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates.
>   — [...]

In both cases, the argument is a set of overloaded functions which contains one or more function templates - which makes it a non-deduced context, so template argument deduction fails. Thus, clang is correct in rejecting both initializations.

Comment: This is tricky. I'm inclined to think that [temp.deduct.type]/5.5.1 makes it a non-deduced context, meaning that `auto`'s deduction should fail in both cases.

Comment: @gd1 For a more thorough answer on partial ordering, check out [Columbo's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31051322/2069064)

Comment: @Barry I'm not talking about the deduction for `bar` (there's obviously no deduction there), I'm talking about the deduction for `auto`, which is as if you did `template<class M> void meow(M); meow(bar<A>);` and deduce `M`.

Comment: @Barry Remember that template argument deduction happens before overload resolution. So first you need to deduce `M`, and then use the rules in [over.over] to pick an overload. But `M` can't be deduced here because you have an overloaded function set.

Comment: @T.C. There we go. I believe that's now the correct answer?

Comment: I don't think it's the "function templates" subbullet (that's for a *template-name* like `foo`, I think, rather than a *template-id* like `foo<A>`, the latter names a set of function template specializations, not function templates). Rather, the first subbullet applies - deduction succeeds for two members of the overload set -> non-deduced context.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I think you're right. First one fits too, either way.